# Can I link interfaces with different names but same structure in Autosar?

Tags: autosar

the question coming from; I have two interfaces they are actually contains the same information inside; and I need to connect these 2 interfaces let say one is sender and the other one is receiver.
so while creating these component interfaces names are different.

Can I connect these interfaces together?
and one more step: can I some how bind these interfaces together. Somehow telling Autosar solution provider tool that these two interfaces actually the same?

If there is no this option, wouldn't be good? even maybe we can bind interfaces by connecting item by item custom.

Answer (score 0):

AUTOSAR defines very detailed compatibility rules for the creation of `SwConnectors` between `PortPrototype`s. Compatibility is checked on various levels. The individual rules are too complex to reiterate in one answer. If you want to get more information about the details, please read chapter 6 of the document TPS Software Component Template.

If you know what you are doing, you can even overrule the compatibility rules by means of so-called `PortInterfaceMapping`s.

To answer the concrete question: yes, it is possible to connect `PortPrototype`s that are typed by different `PortInterface`s that have different `shortName`s as long as the applicable compatbility rules for the content of the `PortInterface`s are fulfilled.

A „binding“ of `PortInterface`s is not supported by the standard.